# Package naming convention Android

Tags: android, google-play

I have an Android App, which has two flavors: Basic and Advanced.
The Basic is already on the AppStore, with a package name of form com.domain.something. I would like to publish the second as com.domain.something.advanced. Is it possible? Or is the fact that the second is a sub package of the first would cause trouble?

Comment: It is possible , and that is how you need to do it exactly if all those all applications from the same  publisher,path hierarchy is useful in that case in order to recognize them

Comment: If you need to clear more com.wad.games.advanced for a package name indicates games.advanced app created by a programmer/owned by wad.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and will not cause any problems in the Play Store.

You will want to read the [Configure Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) guide for more information on setting up a product flavor for your "advanced" version. You can use the `applicationIdSuffix` in your build types or product flavors to set a suffix on your application ID for that particular variant.

Your build.gradle will end up looking something like this:

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.something"
    }

    buildTypes {...}

    productFlavors {
        basic {...}

        advanced {
            applicationIdSuffix ".advanced"
        }
    }
}
```

You can then either programmatically check your product flavor with the generated `BuildConfig` class, or put your code for the `advanced` version in the `advanced` product flavor's source folder (`/src/advanced/java`, `/src/advanced/res`, etc.).

Comment: If we use `advanced {
            applicationIdSuffix ".advanced"
        }`  and build a signed apk that will come out with the package name > `applicationId + applicationIdSuffix` am i right?

Comment: @Charuka that is correct. When you generate your signed APK in Android Studio you can select the product flavor you want to use, or if you are using the gradle command line you can specify the product flavor by using the respective task name (e.g. `assembleAdvancedRelease`). All APKs using the `basic` flavor will still have the regular `applicationId` without `.advanced` at the end.

Comment: Great!! Thanks for your answer Tanis